# Do I need to use the less than (<) operator in my for loops for auto-vectorization?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've just read through the [auto-vectorization page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh872235.aspx) and still don't really understand exactly which loops would be vectorized.

On [the MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/04/12/what-is-vectorization.aspx) we get this example of a loop that can be auto-vectorized:

```
const int N = 1000;
float a[N], b[N];
// Initialize a[i] = i; b[i] = 100 + i
int main() 
{
  for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) a[n] += b[n];
}
```

I usually use the `n != N` idiom as opposed to `n < N`; does that matter like it does in OpenMP? Or does auto-vectorization work regardless?

Comment: Why not use `/Qvec-report:2` and find out? [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj614596.aspx)

Comment: @McAden yup it works.

Comment: reworded into answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you know every in-and-out about how all the auto-vecorization works you're going to have a hard time predicting what every loop is going to do. What I feel would be a better approach if this is important to you would be to use `/Qvec-report:2` as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj614596.aspx) which should tell you whether or not a given loop is auto-vectorized and why.